# maxOccurs restriction based on node attribute in XML

Tags: xsd

I have following XSD:

```
<xs:element name="constGroup">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="const" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="activateBitmask" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This describes a group of constants that may have a bitmask. As I have a 32-bit integer in the underlying program I need to restrict the occurences of `<const>` to 32 when the attribute `activateBitmask` of the parent is set to true. I cannot set it hard to 32 because there are some groups of constants without bitmask that count more than 32 members.

Comment: Can't do that in xsd v1.0.  Does whatever you are doing it in support v1.1?  Don't know if that is possible in v1.1 either.

Comment: I don't know if my document is xsd 1.1 ready. Are there any compatiblity issues from v1.0 to 1.1?